# ERROR: .whl is not supported wheel on this platform while installing tensorflow on Raspberry Pi

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to install TensorFlow on Raspberry Pi 4 Ubuntu 20 python version 3.8 and pip version 20 and this error is always appearing. 
I need these specific versions (I also tried using python version 3.7 and it didn't work either)
I saw some suggestions to downgrade my python version to Python 2.7 but I need 3+ versions.
What can i do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it using tensorflow lite.